# How to write a regex with groups including greedy matching and negative lookbehind

Tags: python, regex

Should be a fairly simple problem but it's one that's had me stumped for ages now. I want to write a regular expression that matches a string of any length of any characters, followed by 3 - 4 uppercase letters or numbers as long as that string doesn't start with a 'D', followed by the string 'ABCD', followed by a '.', followed by three digits. So it would look something like this:

```
r"(.*)(?<!D[A-Z0-9]{3,4})(ABCD.\d\d\d)"
```

The second group is the one I want to capture/ extract and it's the one I can't get right. It needs be greedy matching (i.e. try to match 4 uppercase letters as long as the first one isn't a D, and the fourth character isn't the A from the 'ABCD' string). so if I ran it against the the following strings:

```
"a \ranDom \ str1ng\DADDABCD.123"
"a diff3r3nt\ranD0m \ str1ng\ DCDZAABCD.123"
"a 3rd\r4ndom \ str1nng\ ADDABCD.123"
"a\ diff3r3nt\ranD0m \ str1ng\CDZAABCD.123"
"a\ diff3r3nt\ranD0m \ str1ng\CDZAABCD-2.123"
```

It would return:

```
None
None
ADD
CDZA
None
```

Comment: Sorry, but didn't you mention you wanted to get all text from the start and before the 3 or 4 letters into Group 1? Or is that just "wording" issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this regex with couple of lookahead conditions:

```
\b(?!D)[A-Z\d]{3,4}(?=ABCD\.\d{3}\b)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/KPBLKp/1)

**RegEx Details:**

- `\b`: Word boundary
- `(?!D)`: Lookahead to assert that `D` is at next position
- `[A-Z\d]{3,4}`: Match an upper case letter or digit 3 to 4 times
- `(?=ABCD\.\d{3}\b)`: Lookahead to assert that we have `ABCD.` followed by 3 digits and a word boundary ahead of current position

**Code:**

```
import re

arr = ["a \ranDom \ str1ng\DADDABCD.123",
"a diff3r3nt\ranD0m \ str1ng\ DCDZAABCD.123",
"a 3rd\r4ndom \ str1nng\ ADDABCD.123",
"a\ diff3r3nt\ranD0m \ str1ng\CDZAABCD.123",
"a\ diff3r3nt\ranD0m \ str1ng\CDZAABCD-2.123"]

reg = re.compile(r'\b(?!D)[A-Z\d]{3,4}(?=ABCD\.\d{3}\b)')

for i in arr:
    m = reg.search(i)
    print (m.group() if m else m)
```

**Output:**

```
None
None
ADD
CDZA
None
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```py
^(.*)\b(?!D)([A-Z0-9]{3,4})(ABCD\.\d{3})$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/QDjFfH/2/). Details:

- `^` - start of string
- `(.*)` - Group 1: any zero or more chars as many as possible
- `\b` - a word boundary
- `(?!D)` - no `D` immediately to the right of the current location
- `([A-Z0-9]{3,4})` - Group 2: three or four uppercase ASCII letters or digits
- `(ABCD\.\d{3})` - Group 3: `ABCD`, `.` and three digits
- `$` - end of string.

Note that you need to escape the `.` if you need to match a literal dot char.

In Python, define the pattern with a raw string literal:

```py
pattern = r'^(.*)\b(?!D)([A-Z0-9]{3,4})(ABCD\.\d{3})$'
```